# What does this mean: "I'll be with you in a minute"?

Tags: meaning

What does this mean: "I'll be with you in a minute"? Does it mean "I'll call you after one minute" or "I'll contact you after one minute" or something else?

Comment: If I say it to someone, it tends to mean `at some point in the future I may pay attention to you`.

Comment: It seems to me it can almost be interpreted literally, so long as you substitute for "one minute" an indefinite but short period of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well usually this is used when speaking face-to-face, and is taken to mean

```
I'm occupied right now, and I'll speak to you in some (short period of) time.
```

Not exactly one minute, but a short enough time. Similar usage to "Just a second" or "Gimme a sec"

<s>If on the phone, it should probably mean he'll call back after a minute or so.</s>

Updated:

As @Martha says - On the phone, this would likely mean *you should hold*.
The correct statement if he intends to ring you back would be

```
"I'll get back to you in a minute".
```

Comment: He'll call back or he expects you to wait on the phone for a short while?

Comment: @darius: could be both - but waiting on the phone could get boring ;)

Answer (score 5):

As JoseK said, this is most often used in person, and it means something like "hold on, let me finish this, and then I'll be able to help you/talk to you."

If someone said this to me on the phone, I would definitely interpret it as "please hold", ***not*** "I'll call you back", and *most certainly **not*** "Please call back in a minute".